# Access own properties in Javascript constructor?

Tags: javascript, class, constructor

I've got a class, something like this:

```js
class Server {
    constructor() {
        this.server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
            this.doSomething()
        });
    }

    doSomething() {
        console.log("Working")
    }
}
```

I want to call my doSomething() function from inside the constructor, how can I do this? I've tried doing `this.doSomething()` and `doSomething()`, both say they are not a function. Also, say in the constructor I did `console.log(this.someValue)`, it logs undefined. How can I access the classes own properties/methods? Is it even possible? Thanks.

Comment: `this.doSomething()` will call it. If you get an error, post the code that produces that error

Comment: I have now found the issue, the `this` is referring to the callback function on the HTTP server. Is there a way I can almost "go up 1 level" with `this` keyword?

Comment: use an arrow function: `http.createServer((req, res) => { ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Yousaf said, all you need to do is use an arrow function instead. Here's an example that shows this in action, using `setTimeout` instead of `http.createServer`:

```js
class Server {
    constructor() {
        this.server = setTimeout(() => {
            this.doSomething();
        }, 0);
    }

    doSomething() {
        console.log("Working");
    }
}

new Server();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Server {
    constructor() {
        const _this = this;
        this.server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
            _this.doSomething()
        });
    }

    doSomething() {
        console.log("Working")
    }
}
```